# Where do I catch an exception thrown during the evaluation of the await-ready or the await-suspend expression of the initial await expression?

Tags: c++, exception, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-coroutine

[Here](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.coroutine#5)'s how a coroutine behaves, i.e. like this,

```cpp
{
   promise-type promise promise-constructor-arguments ;
   try {
      co_await promise.initial_suspend() ;
      function-body
   } catch ( ... ) {
      if (!initial-await-resume-called)
         throw ;
      promise.unhandled_exception() ;
   }
final-suspend :
   co_await promise.final_suspend() ;
}
```

and, more specifically [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.coroutine#5.3) is the meaning of `initial-await-resume-called`:

> *initial-await-resume-called* is initially `false` and is set to `true` immediately before the evaluation of the *await-resume* expression ([[expr.await]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.await)) of the initial await expression,

So I understand that, if I use a `promise-type` that has an `initial_suspend` returning an awaiter with an `await_resume` that `throw`s an exception, that exception will be caught in the `catch(...)` above an be deal with via the `promise.unhandled_exception()` call. (And that's indeed precisely what I observe if I move the `throw 2;` statement form `await_suspend` to `await_resume` in the code below.)

But what if the exception is `throw`n before that, say in `await_ready` or `await_suspend`?

Where can such an exception be caught?

Here's the awaiter that accepts suspension and `throw`s right after suspension took place, but not immediately before resumption starts:

```cpp
struct Thrower {
    bool await_ready() const { return false; }
    void await_suspend(auto) const { throw 2; }
    void await_resume() const {}
};
```

here's the `initial_suspend` and `unhandled_exception` methods of the promise type:

```cpp
auto initial_suspend() {
    return Thrower{};
}
void unhandled_exception() {
    std::cout << "caught in unhandled_exception" << std::endl;
}
```

and here's the `main`:

```cpp
int main() {
    try {
        mycoro(3);
    } catch(...) {
        std::cout << "caught in main" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

As far as the standard is concerned, [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.await#5.1) I read that

> If the evaluation of *await-suspend* exits via an exception, the exception is caught, the coroutine is resumed, and the exception is immediately rethrown ([[except.throw]](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.throw)).

But from that clause, which I think it's supposed to hold for **any** *await-suspend* expression, including the one produced for the initial await expression, I would expect that wrapping either the call site of the coroutine (as above) or the body of the coroutine itself in a `try`/`catch` should do the job.

However, compiling and executing the program on Linux with GCC 12.2.1 ( `g++ -std=c++20 mycoro.cpp -g -O0 -o mycoro && ./mycoro`) results in the following output:

```
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

whereas I expected the exception to be caught in the `main`'s `catch` block.

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/o43jfdjja) the complete example (code also copied below), where GCC exhibits the same error I observe on my maching, whereas Clang behaves as I would have expected. Since they disagree, I'm not sure which one is if any is showing the correct behavior.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <coroutine>

struct Thrower {
    bool await_ready() const { return false; }
    void await_suspend(auto) const { throw 2; }
    void await_resume() const {}
};

class CoroTask {
  public:
    CoroTask(const CoroTask&) = delete;
    CoroTask& operator=(const CoroTask&) = delete;
    struct promise_type {
        auto get_return_object() {
            return CoroTask{CoroHdl::from_promise(*this)};
        }
        auto initial_suspend() {
            return Thrower{};
        }
        void unhandled_exception() {
            std::cout << "caught in unhandled_exception" << std::endl;
        }
        void return_void() {}
        auto final_suspend() noexcept {
            return std::suspend_always{};
        }
    };
    using CoroHdl = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>;
  private:
    CoroHdl hdl;
  public:
    CoroTask(auto h) : hdl{h} {}
    ~CoroTask() {
        if (hdl) hdl.destroy();
    }

    bool resume() const {
        if (!hdl || hdl.done()) {
            return false;
        }
        hdl.resume();
        return !hdl.done();
    }
};

CoroTask mycoro(int max)
{
  for (int val = 1; val <= max; ++val) {
    co_await std::suspend_always{};
  }
}


int main() {
    try {
        mycoro(3);
    } catch(...) {
        std::cout << "caught in main" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a proper [mcve] for this?

Comment: @NicolBolas, but I've provided it at the compiler explorer link...

Comment: Anyway, I've added the example in the question. I don't know how to make it more minimal than this.